# How send data (selectItem of listView) from xaml to ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want get data selected in my viewModel

this is my xaml, but i donot know how solved my xaml, because this is bad, how use my behavior here in my xaml?

```
<ListView.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:ItemTappedBehavior EventName="ItemSelected">
                    <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedTagChanged}" />
                </behaviors:ItemTappedBehavior>
            </ListView.Behaviors>
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding actors}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
```

in my behindcode

```
public partial class ActorsView : ContentPage
    {
        public AccountsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                Actor selectedItem = (Actor)e.Item;
                Console.WriteLine("WORK"+ Actor.Name);
            }
```

but i want to get in my viewModel, dont in my behind code

i've seen to solved is with commands, or behaviors

this is my viewModel:

```
public class ActorsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public List<Actor> actors { get; set; }

        public AccountsViewModel(IActorManager actorManager)
            : base()
        {
```

Edit, i am using commands but i dont know how use the answer from John Livermore, i want to use and show the console Console.WriteLine("ROW");.

```
public class ItemTappedBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
    {
        public ICommand Command { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(ListView bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ListView bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        public Command SelectedTagChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(row =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ROW");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your ViewModel.cs, and your Page.cs constructor.

Comment: @Greggz what page.cs? i edited my question

Comment: The Page.cs where you have your code behind

Comment: @Greggz i edited my question, see please, i dont have a lot of code

Comment: How are you binding your `actors`, you have not binded the `BindingContext` of your page with the `ActorsViewModel`

Comment: Please follow a tutorial. This is basic stuff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: @Greggz the binding is made with locator from other class

Comment: @Greggz is not necesary do as the johnLivermore's answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209854/discussion-between-mikkylekyle-and-greggz).

Comment: Does your ListView have items visible in UI?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar yes i have items visibles

Comment: Then I would suggest to add a property in `ActorsViewModel` say `SelectedActor` and Bind the `SelectedItem` property of `ListView` to it.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar i need use commands

Comment: OK then, follow johnLivermore's answer that you suggest and comment if you face any difficulties.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar i edited my question, i dont know how use the behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209864/discussion-between-nikhileshwar-and-mikkylekyle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had asked for a simpler Behavior for ListView selection changed. Please use the following:

Following class is inherited from [`BehaviorBase`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/BehaviorBase.cs) which takes care of BindingContext allocation.

1. On the `OnAttachedTo` override the ItemSelected event is hooked.
2. On the `OnDetachingFrom` override the ItemSelected event is unhooked.
3. `Command` bindable property Binds to the Command in `ViewModel`
4. In the event the `e.SelectedItem` is passed to the Command. (Change
   it to whatever value you wish to pass)

```cs
public class SelectionChangedEventBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SelectionChangedEventBehavior), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        AssociatedObject.ItemSelected += AssociatedObject_ItemSelected;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        AssociatedObject.ItemSelected -= AssociatedObject_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Command != null)
        {
            Command.Execute(e.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Xaml

```cs
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <local:SelectionChangedEventBehavior Command="{Binding SelectionCommand}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
        </ListView>
```

ViewModel

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Command<object> SelectionCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SelectionCommand = new Command<object>(OnSelection);
    }

    private void OnSelection(object item)
    {
        var selectedActor = (item as Actor);
    }
}
```

Hope this could be useful for you. If possible use the [EventToCommandBehavior](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs) as whole, just because you can reuse it for any control and any event.

Answer (score -1):

In your XAML do the following:

Set your `<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding actors}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">`

to be  `<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding actors}" SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedActor, Mode=TwoWay}>`

In your view model which your current XAML is bound to, create two new variables as so:

```
private Actor selectedActor;
public Actor SelectedActor {
     get {return selectedActor;}
     set {
       selectedActor = value;
       if(selectedActor != null) {//set properties here if needed}

    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedActor"); //or however you raise your events, this is a 
    //custom method i've made
}
```

Now, where we define our `actors` item source, we will also define what a `selectedActor` is as so:

```
//get your actors, loop over them and add them to the list of actors
var actorItem = new Actor();
actors.Add(actorItem);

//outside of list raise the property changed event on your actors list. 
OnPropertyChanged("actors")
```

That is a the pattern that i've used at work to get my selected item. If you then need to do something with it you could define it within the SelectedActor variable. For us our app is a hybrid between old xamarin (.Android and .iOS) and .Forms, so we pass Actions from the native level to the view model (ex: loading the summary page for the selected item)

Comment: Some braces are missing in the code